# Pairwise non-isomorphic interval-isomorphic lattices

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, lattice-theory, posets

Let us call a lattice $(L,\leq)$ *interval-isomorphic* if for all $a<b \in L$ we have $L \cong [a,b]$, where $[a,b]=\{x\in L:a\leq x\leq b\}$.

Are there $2^{\aleph_0}$ pairwise non-isomorphic interval-isomorphic lattices on the ground set $\omega$?

Comment: Are there $3$? Maybe I'm just being an idiot here, but the only ones I can think of are the countable atomless Boolean algebra, and the linearly ordered set $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: That's one more than I could imagine. Maybe lexicographic product can make more? Gerhard "Is Low On Imagination Today" Paseman, 2019.09.02.

Comment: Is this property preserved under direct products?

Comment: Would the linearly ordered set $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2] \cup [0,1]$ serve as a 3rd example?

Comment: @Bullet51 I assume you meant $\cap$ instead of $\cup$?

Comment: @WillBrian Good point - first I only could think of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and then somebody mentioned the countable atomless Boolean algebra and I couldn't come up with anything else... But I assumed there must be infinitely many pairwise non-isomorphic such lattices, and "often", if you have countably many, you can find $2^{\aleph_0}$ many. (But vague intuition often leads astray.)

Comment: @Bullet51 Up to isomorphism, $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ is the only linearly ordered example (being the unique countable dense linear order with endpoints).

Comment: @SamHopkins Usually not. Since $L$ embeds as an interval into $L\times L$ (say, by $x\mapsto(x,a)$ for a fixed element $a$), $L\times L$ has the property only if and only if (1) $L$ has the property and (2) $L\simeq L\times L$.

Comment: The generic (or "typical")  $\{0,1\}$-lattice (the Fraisse limit of all finite $\{0,1\}$-lattices) is another example.

Comment: Gabor Czedli has several papers about such lattices, which he calls "fractal": http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~czedli/listak/publist.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but a description of a potential solution.
I conjecture that ``Yes, there
are $2^{\aleph_0}$-many self-similar countable lattices.''

I am pretty sure that any irreducible continuous geometry
has the property that any two proper nontrivial intervals are
isomorphic to each other. I am less confident that the whole
lattice is isomorphic to any of its intervals, but it seems plausible.

But continuous geometries are uncountable, so they do not
answer the question. Nevertheless,
they have countable dense sublattices. One way to construct
such a countable dense sublattice was described by von Neumann:

Let $\mathbb D$ be a countable division ring and let
$PG(\mathbb D, 2^n-1)$ be $(2^n-1)$-dimensional
projective space over $\mathbb D$ equipped with a
dimension function normalized so that the dimension of
the whole space is $1$. There are dimension-preserving
embeddings

$PG(\mathbb D, 1)\leq PG(\mathbb D, 3)\leq PG(\mathbb D, 7)\leq \cdots .$

Let $PG(\mathbb D, \omega)$ be the direct limit of these embeddings.
This is a countable, complemented, modular lattice with normalized dimension
function taking values in the dyadic rationals. It is also a
metric space with metric given by
$d(a,b) = \dim(a\vee b)-\dim(a\wedge b)$.

The continuous geometry over 
$\mathbb D$, $CG(\mathbb D)$,  is the (uncountable) metric completion of
$PG(\mathbb D, \omega)$. But let's hold off and not complete
this lattice. Instead, let's stay with the countable and very homogeneous
modular lattice $PG(\mathbb D, \omega)$. I think it is a good
candidate for a countable lattice isomorphic to each of its
proper intervals.

$PG(\mathbb D, \omega)$ encodes information about $\mathbb D$.
I do not know the circumstances when 
$PG(\mathbb D, \omega)\cong PG(\mathbb D', \omega)$
implies $\mathbb D\cong \mathbb D'$, but in Birkhoff's paper
*Von Neumann and Lattice Theory* the author write
``Curiously, the real and quaternion continuous geometries are isomorphic.''
This indicates that the related implication
*$CG(\mathbb D)\cong CG(\mathbb D')$ implies $\mathbb D\cong \mathbb D'$*
can fail, but that Birkhoff found it curious when it happened,
even for closely related division algebras.
I'm not sure what this says about the implication for 
$PG(\mathbb D, \omega)$ in place of $CG(\mathbb D)$.

But let's suppose that it is often the case that
$\mathbb D\not\cong \mathbb D'$ implies
$PG(\mathbb D, \omega)\not\cong PG(\mathbb D', \omega)$
There surely ARE $2^{\aleph_0}$-many
choices for $\mathbb D$.
For example, 
$\mathbb D = \mathbb Q[\sqrt{p_1}, \sqrt{p_2},\ldots]$,
where we adjoin some set of square roots of primes to $\mathbb Q$,
is a countable field, and fields constructed this way are not
isomorphic if they are contructed from different sets of primes.

Thus, I propose the lattices $PG(\mathbb D, \omega)$ for countable fields
$\mathbb D$ as likely candidates to solve this problem.

[In the comments to the question
it is noted that the countable atomless
Boolean algebra is an example of a countable self-similar
lattice. This example may be thought of as arising from
the above construction starting with $\mathbb D$
equal to the ``field of one element''. By this I mean
replace $PG(\mathbb D, 2^n-1)$ in von Neumann's
construction with the power set lattice with $2^n$ atoms.]